# Azure AD B2C user creation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any way to automate azure ad b2c user creation process.I am using custom policy for passwordless email verification.
I want to create user automatically from share-point list,like if I add user there it will add to B2C automatically.
what are the possible solutions to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possible solution is to use the graph api, in combination with power automate/flow or logic apps.. 
eg. make a flow that monitors the sharepoint list and on create, then run a graph api call to create a user in the aad b2c. 
the graph reference for creating users in aad b2c would be the following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api

I'm sure there are other ways, but personally this seems like a fairly decent way to do it? Hope that helps a bit.

Regards,